# Exclude future dates from a given date using React Datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

When using the React Datepicker library with [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to manipulate dates, one can exclude given days as captured below and described in the React Datepicker [documentation](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-exclude-dates);

```js
// Exclude today and yesterday.
excludeDates = {[moment(), moment().subtract(1, "days")]}
```

How can I exclude future dates from a given date?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [`filterDate`](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-filter-dates) check and return *true* if the date is in past.

The snippet below illustrates how to use `filterDate`;

```js
<DatePicker
  selected = {this.state.date}
  onChange = {this.handleChange}
  filterDate = {(date) => {
    return moment() > date;
  }}
  placeholderText = "Select a weekday"
/>
```

Comment: I've used the following to disable future dates (from today onwards):

filterDate={date => {
          return new Date() > date;
        }}

Answer (score 0):

You can use Datepicker's `minDate` & `maxDate` options.

Eg: if you want to exclude all the dates after 10 days,

```
<DatePicker
selected={new Date()}
onChange={this.handleChange}
maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 10)}
/>
```

If you want to exclude all past dates and dates after 10 days.

```
<DatePicker
selected={new Date()}
onChange={this.handleChange}
minDate={new Date()}
maxDate={addDays(new Date(), 10)}
/>
```